# DRAGNN local/global training

Tags: syntaxnet

This is a parameter which present the training ways of syntaxnet models is local or global, however, I can't find the related parameter in the DRAGNN models. Can someone help me?

Comment: Kindly add more details - the more you will elaborate your problem, the easier it will be for users to help you out!